# Caterpillar identification (France)

Tags: identification

I live in France, my house is in a small hamlet of ~5 houses and we are surrounded by fields (at the moment they are growing onions I think).

I am literally invaded by this caterpillar. I have them all over the walls of my house. For the moment they have not done anything to my outdoor plants.

What are they? How come I have so many caterpillars?

[image: Caterpillars]